# Discord.js NewMember Presence Status returning same value as OldMember

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to create something that will only return when an old presence changed to a new presence, but those 2 return the same value:

```js
client.on("presenceUpdate", function(oldMember, newMember){
   console.log(newMember.user.presence.status); // Returns same as oldMember
   console.log(oldMember.user.presence.status); // Returns same as newMember
})
```

Comment: How are you getting the `newMember` and `oldMember` objects? You are only logging two objects that are passed to the function - are you sure they have been updated prior to this?

Comment: Regarding to discord.js guide oldMember should be the old object of the new member. That's why I'm confused on this.

Comment: Why are you doing `newMember.user.presence` ? you can simplify this to just `newMember`, the objects it passes in are `Presence` classes not `GuildMember`

Answer (score -1):

The `presenceUpdate` [Check the docs!!](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate) event returns the `oldPresence` and `newPresence` which are a `Presence` object [Check the docs!!](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence). Instead of using the user just get the presence right from the event.

The reason you are getting a presence at all is because you grab the `user` property from the presence itself because the event does not return a member.

```
client.on("presenceUpdate", function(oldPresence, newPresence){
   console.log(oldPresence.status); // Returns old presence
   console.log(newPresence.status); // Returns new presence
})
```

**Note:** The `oldPresence` is not guaranteed so make sure you cross check that first if needed.